# Redirect all pages except a few specific ones

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to use javascript on this, and place in header for all site pages.

//.mysite.com - redirect all pages within this domain to //.mysite.com/home

Except for these 3 page examples, I don't want these redirected.

```
www.mysite.com/page2 
www.mysite.com/article/sat
www.mysite.com/home/message
```

Any ideas? I've never had a request for something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (['/page2', 'article/sat', 'home/message', '/home'].indexOf(window.location.pathname) < 0)
    window.location = 'www.mysite.com/home'
```

no need for jquery

Comment: That redirects all including 3 I didn't want to redirect, how do I get an exception for the 3 I don't want redirected?

Comment: when you are on `www.mysite.com/page2 `, what do you get when you type `window.location.pathname` in the console?

Comment: cool. Make sure your page don't end up being 'www.mysite.com/page2/' because the last `/` would make this fail, or account for this in the filtration